# ための usage in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> 貴方は生物だから、鉱物の死を理解できないのよ。だから鉱物の死を『視る』ためには、まず彼らと同じ指向性を持つ**ための**回線に繋がらないといけない。

I really can't understand this

I know that

> AのためのB　→　B for the sake/benfit of A

But it does not make sense here, at least to me.

Comment: Death of minerals? Directionality? I'm not sure I would even understand a perfect English translation of this. Maybe more context would help, or any translation that you have been able to come up with.

Comment: I am reading tsukihime and the protagonist can see the death of living beings and other things.
In the eyes there are circuits that allows him to see the death of all things.

He was watching a building when he saw those lines of death.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ため also has the definition of "purpose, objective, aim."

> まず彼らと同じ指向性を持つための回線に繋がらないといけない。
>   First you must be connected with the circuit that has the purpose of taking the same alignment as them.

Comment: I am feeling like an idiot now.
I kept thinking 持つ=have instead of take
I understood it immediately after reading yours.
Thanks!

Comment: No problem! I figured 持つ was part of the problem. It took me a while to figure out why translating it as "having" felt wrong. It's rather misleading of dictionaries to define it as "to hold, to have" when that would actually be 持っている.