# "私には、セーラームーンを見るのを止めるための強い意志が欠けている。"

Tags: words, verbs

I tried looking up this word in Denshi Jisho, but to no avail. What does "ため" mean when it is attached to the verb 止める?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ための usage in this sentence](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28550/%e3%81%9f%e3%82%81%e3%81%ae-usage-in-this-sentence)

Answer (score 2):

ため means “in order to” (or “because”, in other contexts); in this case, it's “in order to stop watching Sailor Moon”.

Comment: "For the purpose of ..."  is also a possible rendering.